# Swagger - How to set default value 0 for int in DTO

Tags: java, json, swagger, dto

My code:

```
@ApiModelProperty(required = true, value = "")
@JsonProperty(value="id")
public int getWareHouseID() {
    return wareHouseID;
}

public void setWareHouseID(int wareHouseID) {
    this.wareHouseID = wareHouseID;
}

@ApiModelProperty(required = true, value = "")
@JsonProperty(value="pId")
public int getParentID() {
    return parentID;
}

public void setParentID(int parentID) {
    this.parentID = parentID;
}
```

Result from swagger:

> {
>     "name": "string",
>     "wareHouseID": "int",
>     "company": "string",
>     "fullname": "string",
>     "address": "string",
>     "parentID": "int"
>   }

My question: Why result for int is String? How can i set default value is: 0.

Thanks all.

Comment: Hi, it looks like both `warehouseID` and `parentID` are the correct types.  Can you share more about your versions and how you're integrating?  You can also use the `example` property in your annotation to set an example value.

Comment: Hi @fehguy, i solved my problem. Tks 4 reply!